# How to match opposite values in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, find

I basically want to eliminate opposite amounts from an imported data frame.

My solution was to build a new data frame ignoring the lines that combined in pairs sum zero.

Considering the following data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['31/07/17', 43020500, 13552.65],
    ['31/07/17', 43020500, 13552.65],
    ['31/07/17', 43020500, 13552.65],
    ['31/07/17', 43020500, 13552.65],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, 241024.48],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, 241024.48],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, 241024.48],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, 241024.48],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, 241024.48],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, -13552.65],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, -13552.65],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, -13552.65],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, -13552.65],
    ['31/08/17', 43020500, -13552.65],
    ['30/06/17', 43020500, 133540.13],
], columns = ['Data', 'Account','Amount']
)

df
Out[34]: 
        Data   Account     Amount
0   31/07/17  43020500   13552.65
1   31/07/17  43020500   13552.65
2   31/07/17  43020500   13552.65
3   31/07/17  43020500   13552.65
4   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
5   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
6   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
7   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
8   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
9   31/08/17  43020500  -13552.65
10  31/08/17  43020500  -13552.65
11  31/08/17  43020500  -13552.65
12  31/08/17  43020500  -13552.65
13  31/08/17  43020500  -13552.65
14  30/06/17  43020500  133540.13
```

[data frame example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b66E5.png)

The expected result is a new data frame composed by Index 4 to 8, 13 and 14 but my code is not working...

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

df = pd.read_excel('ContractAssets_copy.XLSX')
df.sort_values('Date')

dfToList = df['Amount'].tolist()

newdf = []

def index(a_list, value):
    try:
        return a_list.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None

for number in dfToList:
    key = index(dfToList, dfToList[number] * -1)
    if key == None:
        newdf.append(df[number])

newdf
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Note that e.g. you have **4** values of *13552.65* but the number of
opposite values (*-13552.65*) is **5**.

So if each value eliminates just **one** opposite value then in this case one
negative value should be left (the other solution does not respect this
principle).

Start from defining a function to eliminate "unwanted" rows (from the
current group of rows):

```
def eliminate(grp):
    grpSorted = grp.sort_values('Amount')
    amt = grpSorted.Amount
    nNeg = np.count_nonzero(amt.lt(0))
    nPos = amt.size - nNeg
    if nNeg == 0 or nPos == 0:  # No opposite values
        return grp
    vDiff = nNeg - nPos
    return grpSorted.head(vDiff) if vDiff > 0 else grpSorted.tail(-vDiff)
```

Then add *AmountAbs* column:

```
df['AmountAbs'] = df.Amount.abs()
```

as we should group rows just on absolute value of *Amount*.

And finally you can do the required grouping and apply the above function to
each group:

```
df.groupby('AmountAbs').apply(eliminate)\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)\
    .drop(columns=['AmountAbs'])
```

"Finishing actions" in the above instruction involve:

- dropping of *AmountAbs* from the index (leave only the original index),
- dropping of *AmountAbs* column.

If you wish, you can add `.sort_index()` to the above instruction, to
restore original row order.

## Edit

There is yet shorter solution, without creating any auxiliary column
(and dropping it at the end).

The elimination function is slightly different:

```
def elim(grp):
    grpSorted = grp.sort_values('Amount')
    amt = grpSorted.Amount
    nNeg = np.count_nonzero(amt.lt(0))  # No of negative values
    nPos = amt.size - nNeg              # No of positive values
    vDiff = nNeg - nPos
    return grpSorted.head(vDiff) if vDiff > 0 else grpSorted.tail(-vDiff)
```

And to apply it, run:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: abs(df.loc[x, 'Amount']))\
    .apply(elim).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove anything that has the opposite value:

```py
df =df[~df['Amount'].isin(-1*df['Amount'])]

df
Out[36]: 
        Data   Account     Amount
4   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
5   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
6   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
7   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
8   31/08/17  43020500  241024.48
14  30/06/17  43020500  133540.13
```